# it possible to put mdframed environment inside tabular environment?

Tags: tables, mdframed, tabulary

I try to use colored framed boxes inside tabular environments.
Is it possible to used "mdframed" environment for it?

Unfortunately, the code below does not work (it gives:
`«! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.»`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | l |}
22222

\begin{mdframed}
1111
\end{mdframed}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Is there any magic to do it (or may be there exists another colored frame boxes package, *compatible* with tabular/tabulary/ environment)?

Update: Actually, I work with ReStructedText → (Sphinx) → Latex → (xelatex) → PDF generation, and have low options to customize generated latex code.  I use some mdframed environment for notes/warnings/admonitions, because they frequently breaks between pages, and mdframed looks best options for it. But small notes, should be OK inside tables, so I trying to make universal environment, that works within and without tables.

Update2: I solved my problem by monkey-patching latex tables generation by sphinx, but still interested if any solution exists to put framed box inside "tabular" without specifying fixed "parbox" width for columns.

Comment: Try to change `|l|` to `|p{10cm}|`, if the `|` are really needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `l` column type with a `p` (parbox) type, however, the width must be specified too.

Make sure to use sufficient zoom-factor for the viewer, as the lines tend to be not displayed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{10cm} |}
\begin{mdframed}
1111
\end{mdframed} \\
\begin{tcolorbox}
1111
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 

If I specify column width or wrap "mdframed" inside minipage with given width, all OK.

But unfortunately I cannot specify column width for tabular (latex code automatically generated from ReStructuredText by Sphinx, and Sphinx entrust Latex to find optimal column widths basing on table content).

Comment: @StasFomin: I'll try to find another way

Comment: I solved my problem by monkey-patching latex tables generation by sphinxdoc, but still interested if any solution exists to put framed box inside "tabular" without specifing fixed width for columns. Thank you again!